# harmon.ie not loading on outlook 2016 startup

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2016, harmon.ie

When I start Outlook the harmon.ie add-in is not deactivated but disabled and if I go to the com-add-ins menu the load behavior is "not loaded". How could I set the load behavior to load on startup?

e.g. I tried these solutions:
https://hubone.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200019219-Things-to-check-if-Harmon-ie-does-not-load-in-Outlook ;
https://www.outlook-apps.com/inactive-outlook-add-ins/ ;

But there are no such registry entries for harmon.ie add-in so that I cannot change the specified values.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Is this a programming question? Have you tried to contact harmon.ie  support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the local user profile on the windows machine eventually solved the issue. After recreating the profile I installed harmon.ie and started outlook. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to download our latest 5.3.1 version from our web site (https://harmon.ie)

There are few configuration options that may impact plugin availability:
•   File -> Slow and Disabled plugins
•   Double check if harmon.ie listed here – if so, select ‘Always load this plugin’.
•   File -> Options -> Addins -> Manage Disabled Items
•   If harmon.ie is listed, remove it from disabled item lists and re-enable via ‘Manage COM Addins’.
•   Check value LoadBehavior=3 under [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Outlook.Sidebar.AddInShim]
•   If LoadBehavior is set to different value than 3 - set the value to 3 and restart Outlook.
•   Also double check LoadBehavior value under [HKLM\Software[Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Outlook.Sidebar.AddInShim] – the value there must be set to LoadBehavior=3.
•   Delete user.config from %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft_Corporation\ harmony_Path_n1uz4of1wqm1raru2xbg1ix44vfujobn \15.0.4551.1511 (the path may be different in your environment)
•   Uninstall harmon.ie and restart Outlook - check under File -> Options -> Addins -> Manage COM Addins if harmon.ie may still be listed there after uninstallation - if so, using "Remove" button in the dialog and re-install harmon.ie.
•   You may also confirm whether harmon.ie add-in works OK when no other add-ins are enabled- temporarily disable all other add-ins via Tools -> Options -> Add-ins -> Manage COM Addins.
•   Try adding following registry setting PreferredCLRVersion=v4.0 (sample script included)
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\PreferredCLRVersion]
@="v4.0"
This configuration option instructs harmon.ie to load .NET framework 4.0 - by default, .NET 2.0 or 3.5 are used.
•   You may also try running Microsoft Office repair operation - we have seen customer reports that a repair operation may in some scenarios restore plugin availability.

---- Jean

Comment: Thanks Jean,
but nothing of your suggestions helped. There was no key like Outlook.Sidebar.AddInShim and I created it manually in [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\]. In [HKLM\Software[Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Outlook.Sidebar.AddInShim] all of the keys were created and the loadbehavior value was set to 3. I also created PreferredCLRVersion Key and String @ ="v4.0".
After these tries I deleted user.config and also uninstalled harmon.ie but it still shows as disabled even if it's not deactivated.

Nicolas

Comment: I suggest you repair or install .net 4.x framework. Please uninstall harmon.ie, download and copy the below files inside the same directory. 
Run as administrator HarmonieSharePointSetup.exe to trigger the installation (the fact the reg keys are not present on your side may point to some permission problem)

ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/HarmonieSharePointSetup.x86.msi
ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/HarmonieSharePointSetup.exe

Comment: every installation I did was made as administrator. I also tried repairing .net 4.x framework and checked for newest version. After that I did reinstallation. Interesting thing: When I uninstalled harmon.ie and started the .exe file the program told me that there is another version already installed and asked for update the installed version. Then I click yes and the installer runs.

Answer (score 0):

-In order to rule out any plugin conflict would you please check whether any additional plugins are enabled in Outlook - if so, disable (temporarily) all other add-ins except harmon.ie To disable Outlook add-ins
•   Go under File -> Options -> Add-ins -> Manage COM Add-ins and click Go...
•   Deselect all add-ins except harmon.ie and click OK.

Restart Outlook - and go back under File -> Options -> Add-ins to verify that harmon.ie is the only add-in listed in the Active application add-ins section.

Then please run the following recovery procedure:

-Please stop Outlook.

-Uninstall harmon.ie from control panel, program feature

-Delete all dirs.  C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\harmony_Path_pzllr20oqrnqmrstb3lfbn4njpshdzry (path can slightly change)

-Delete C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Local\Mainsoft and C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Roaming\Mainsoft

-Register the attached clean_Mainsoft_Reg_New reg file. at ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/Clean%20Mainsoft%20Reg_New.reg.zip (please use this one)

-Register the PreferredCLRversion registry key at ftp://free:free@ftpus.mainsoft.com/PreferredCLRVersion4.0.zip  (please use this one)

-Reinstall harmon.ie. Please install our latest 5.3.1 from our web site.

-Start Outlook

Comment: Still no success. Tried your solution several times, but nothing of these worked...

Comment: I will try to delete the user profile. When login to the same computer with another account it work's. So maybe a new profile will solve the issue.